# Join 4 tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have four tables which I want to join. I tried but I am getting some redundant values.
Here are the table structures:

**custacdetails :**

```
cid - FK
acno - PK
```

**custac:**

```
acno - FK
acscheme
```

**custdetails**

```
cid - PK
fname
```

**same_ben:**

```
cid
bacno
```

Now I want to get all the list of accounts and their respective details whose account matches with the bacno in same_ben by supplying only the cid.

Here is my **query**:

```
SELECT fname,
  lname,
  acscheme,
  actype,
  sb.bacno,
  rdate
FROM custdetails cd,
  custac ca,
  custacdetails cad,
  same_ben sb
WHERE cad.acno = ca.acno
AND cd.custid  = cad.custid
AND cad.acno  IN
  (SELECT bacno FROM same_ben WHERE custid=?
  )
AND sb.bacno = cad.acno
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very hard to read, as you're trying to do inner joins a very long way around. I'd try to simplify your query first, using the following (not tested, but should be right), and then work out where you're getting duplicate information and need to make your joins more strict (or use a different type of join)

```
select 
    fname, lname, acscheme, actype, sb.bacno, rdate
from custdetails cd        
inner join custacdetails cad
    on cd.custid = cad.custid
inner join custac ca
    on cad.acno = ca.acno
inner join same_ben sb
    on sb.custid = cd.custid
    and sb.bacno = cad.acno
where
    cd.cust_id = ??
```

Not directly related to your question, but your field names and table names aren't very descriptive... expand both and you'll make life a lot easier, and a lot easier for us to understand.

Comment: No, It's not working. "no rows selected " message is shown. And one thing I will provide the where condition to custid field in same_ben table not the custdetails table.

Comment: I hadn't actually tested the code (I don't have your database), so the joins probably aren't right, but it should still help you clean your code up. Using joins like above, the "structure" clauses are all contained within the joins, and the "where" is your real logic